# SQL SERVER - OBTENER PRIMER DIA DEL AÑO DEL MES ANTERIOR AL ULTIMO DIA DEL MES ANTERIOR

Tags: sql-server, busqueda-rango-de-fechas

necesito obtener un reporte donde me muestre el total de ventas de clientes efectuadas desde el primer dia del año del mes anterior hasta el ultimo dia del mes anterior, originalmente usaba esta instruccion:

```
WHERE FECHA_V BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(YEAR,0,GETDATE()),0),23)
AND EOMONTH ( CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())- 1, 0),23))
```

pero se presenta el problema sobre si el reporte se ejecutara en el mes de enero 2023, este debe mostrar las ventas efectuadas desde el 01-01-2022 al 31-12-2022 y asi como lo tengo yo, me marcaria error ya que me tomara el rango del 01-01-2023 al 31-12-2022, por lo que intento hacerlo asi:

```
WHERE FECHA_V BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(YEAR,0,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())- 1, 0)),0),23) 
AND EOMONTH ( CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())- 1, 0),23))
```

solo que no tengo manera de probarlo ya que en el unico equipo donde tenemos instalado el SQL SERVER no debo cambiarle la fecha del sistema para hacerle pruebas, alguien me comento que existen paginas para probar instrucciones SQL en linea, por lo que solicito su ayuda para ubicarlas o para validarlo o para simplificarlo, les agradeceria mucho su ayuda.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

El cálculo es muy cercano a lo que ya tienes, solo que necesitas agregar la lógica que pides.

También se sencillo probar las fórmulas sin tener que cambiar la fecha del servidor. Solo tienes que crear una tabla con distintas fechas.

```
WITH 
E(n) AS(
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E3(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b, E c
),
cteCal(fecha) AS(
    SELECT DATEADD( dd, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1, '20220101') fecha
    FROM E3
)
SELECT fecha,
    DATEADD( YY, DATEDIFF( YY, 0, DATEADD( MM, -1, fecha)), 0),
    DATEADD( MM, DATEDIFF( MM, 0, fecha), -1)
FROM cteCal;
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo así:

```
Declare @fecha datetime = '20230115'

SELECT 
 DATEADD(yy,
      DATEDIFF(yy,0,(DATEADD(mm,-1,
      DATEADD(mm,
         DATEDIFF(mm,0,@fecha),0)))),0) as primerDiaAñoMesAnterior,
 DATEADD(ms,-3,(
      CAST(DATEADD(dd,1,
         (EOMONTH(@fecha,-1))) AS DATETIME))) as ultimoDiaMesAnterior;
```

[image: Result1]

Fíjate que ambas columnas utilizan la variable @fecha, que puedes cambiar por la función GetDate() cuando lo valides.

Quedando tú código algo así:

```
Where 
Fecha_V >= DATEADD(yy,
      DATEDIFF(yy,0,(DATEADD(mm,-1,
      DATEADD(mm,
         DATEDIFF(mm,0,getdate()),0)))),0) 
And
Fecha_V <= 
DATEADD(ms,-3,(
          CAST(DATEADD(dd,1,
             (EOMONTH(Getdate(),-1))) AS DATETIME)))
```

[Funciones de fecha útiles](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/12/15/funciones-de-fecha-para-datetime-utiles/)

Comment: Tienes mál el cálculo. Estás regresando el primer día del año anterior y están pidiendo el primer día del año al que corresponde el mes anterior.

Comment: Esta cambiado. No era muy difícil, ya que en el enlace suministrado, existen esos "cálculos".